# Difference in behavior when hooking a library function via LD_PRELOAD on Ubuntu and CentOS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, hook, ld-preload

There is a hook function *socketHook.c* that intercepts *socket()* calls:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int socket(int domain, int type, int protocol)
{
    printf("socket() has been intercepted!\n");
    return 0;
}
gcc -c -fPIC socketHook.c
gcc -shared -o socketHook.so socketHook.o
```

And a simple program *getpwuid.c* (1) that just invokes the [getpwuid()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwuid.3p.html) function:

```
#include <pwd.h>

int main()
{
    getpwuid(0);
    return 0;
}
gcc getpwuid.c -o getpwuid
```

*getpwuid()* internally makes a *socket()* call.
On CentOS:

```
$ strace -e trace=socket ./getpwuid
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 3
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)         = 4
```

On Ubuntu:

```
$ strace -e trace=socket ./getpwuid
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 5
socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 5
```

When running (1), *socket()* is intercepted on CentOS, but not on Ubuntu.

**CentOS.** *printf()* from *socketHook.c* is present:

```
$ uname -a
Linux centos-stream 4.18.0-301.1.el8.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Apr 13 16:24:22 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ LD_PRELOAD=$(pwd)/socketHook.so ./getpwuid
socket() has been intercepted!
```

**Ubuntu**(Xubuntu 20.04). *printf()* from *socketHook.c* is NOT present:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ibse-VirtualBox 5.8.0-50-generic #56~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 12 21:46:35 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ LD_PRELOAD=$(pwd)/socketHook.so ./getpwuid
$
```

So my question is:

1. What does it depend on? I think this is affected by the fact that *socket()* is not called directly from the executable, but from getpwuid(), which in turn is called, if I understand correctly, from libc.so
2. How to achieve the same behavior in CentOS as in Ubuntu? I don't want intercept indirect calls from libc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does it depend on?

There are two questions to ask:

1. Which function actually calls the `socket` system call?
2. How is that function getting called.

You can see *how* the `socket` *system call* is invoked by running your program under GDB, and using `catch syscall socket` command. On Ubuntu:

```
(gdb) catch syscall socket    
Catchpoint 1 (syscall 'socket' [41])
(gdb) run 
Starting program: /tmp/a.out 

Catchpoint 1 (call to syscall socket), 0x00007ffff7ed3477 in socket () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:120
120     ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7ed3477 in socket () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:120
#1  0x00007ffff7f08010 in open_socket (type=type@entry=GETFDPW, key=key@entry=0x7ffff7f612ca "passwd", keylen=keylen@entry=7) at nscd_helper.c:171
#2  0x00007ffff7f084fa in __nscd_get_mapping (type=type@entry=GETFDPW, key=key@entry=0x7ffff7f612ca "passwd", mappedp=mappedp@entry=0x7ffff7f980c8 <map_handle+8>) at nscd_helper.c:269
#3  0x00007ffff7f0894f in __nscd_get_map_ref (type=type@entry=GETFDPW, name=name@entry=0x7ffff7f612ca "passwd", mapptr=mapptr@entry=0x7ffff7f980c0 <map_handle>, 
    gc_cyclep=gc_cyclep@entry=0x7fffffffda0c) at nscd_helper.c:419
#4  0x00007ffff7f04fb7 in nscd_getpw_r (key=0x7fffffffdaa6 "0", keylen=2, type=type@entry=GETPWBYUID, resultbuf=resultbuf@entry=0x7ffff7f96520 <resbuf>, 
    buffer=buffer@entry=0x5555555592a0 "", buflen=buflen@entry=1024, result=0x7fffffffdb60) at nscd_getpw_r.c:93
#5  0x00007ffff7f05412 in __nscd_getpwuid_r (uid=uid@entry=0, resultbuf=resultbuf@entry=0x7ffff7f96520 <resbuf>, buffer=buffer@entry=0x5555555592a0 "", buflen=buflen@entry=1024, 
    result=result@entry=0x7fffffffdb60) at nscd_getpw_r.c:62
#6  0x00007ffff7e9e95d in __getpwuid_r (uid=uid@entry=0, resbuf=resbuf@entry=0x7ffff7f96520 <resbuf>, buffer=0x5555555592a0 "", buflen=buflen@entry=1024, 
    result=result@entry=0x7fffffffdb60) at ../nss/getXXbyYY_r.c:255
#7  0x00007ffff7e9dfd3 in getpwuid (uid=0) at ../nss/getXXbyYY.c:134
#8  0x0000555555555143 in main () at t.c:5

(gdb) info sym $pc
socket + 7 in section .text of /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) up
#1  0x00007ffff7f08010 in open_socket (type=type@entry=GETFDPW, key=key@entry=0x7ffff7f612ca "passwd", keylen=keylen@entry=7) at nscd_helper.c:171
171     nscd_helper.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) x/i $pc-5
   0x7ffff7f0800b <open_socket+59>:     callq  0x7ffff7ed3470 <socket>
```

From this we can see that

1. The function `socket` is called. Using `nm -D /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep ' socket'` we can confirm that that function is exported from `libc.so.6`, and thus should be interposable.
2. The caller *does not* call `socket@plt` (i.e. does not use the [procedure linkage table](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/1993)), and so `LD_PRELOAD` will have no effect.

The call from `open_socket()` to `socket()` has been non-interposable since 2004, so it's likely that *this* call isn't intercepted on CentOS either, but some *other* call is. Probably the 3rd one in your `strace` output.

Using above method you should be able to tell where *that* call comes from.

---

> I don't want intercept indirect calls from libc

In that case, `LD_PRELOAD` may be the wrong mechanism to use.

If you want to only intercept `socket()` calls from your own code, it's trivial to redirect them to e.g. `mysocket()` without any need for `LD_PRELOAD`.

You can do that at source level by adding e.g.

```
#define socket mysocket
```

to all your files, or using `-Dsocket=mysocket` argument at compile time.

Alternatively, using the linker `--wrap=socket` will do the redirection without recompiling.

Comment: _"The caller does not call socket@plt, and so LD_PRELOAD will have no effect."_  What is @plt? Is it necessary for the LD_PRELOAD intercept to work? Where can I find out more about this?

Comment: @ibse I've updated the answer. You can read about PLT here: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/1993 and follow the links.